# How to copy a portion of the screen and save it to a bitmap or PNG file in QB64?

Tags: bmp, qb64

I need to copy a specific portion of the screen and save it to a bitmap (BMP) or PNG file after drawing some stuff to that section of the screen. I'm having trouble understanding the new _PUTIMAGE vs GET and PUT. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You'd use [`_NEWIMAGE`](http://qb64.org/wiki/NEWIMAGE) to create a new image in memory, then `_PUTIMAGE` with that new image handle specified as the destination.  After that, you can save the image handle to a BMP file using the [SaveImage](http://qb64.org/wiki/SAVEIMAGE) `SUB` and free the memory afterward using `_FREEIMAGE`.  There is only the `_LOADIMAGE` function to load an image file but not a corresponding `_SAVEIMAGE` statement, so unfortunately the SaveImage `SUB` is the only option without creating your own BMP/PNG file-saving routine.